# Jquery: dynamically appending to context.childNodes[4] not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, canvas

noobish aspiring front end engineer here.I am currently working on an html5 canvas vector drawing app that makes color palette swaps easy. 
I am working on a function that creates a named color variable/object (such as 'primary' or 'secondary') and stores it in its own array for safe keeping BUT ALSO appends it to a color-selector/palette swapper for the menu's of every vector shape that has been created.

The idea is that you draw a shape, select 'primary' (or whatever color variables you have previously created) in that shapes menu and that shapes color is set to whatever primary is, which can be easily changed in the seperate menu for the 'primary' color variable.

I'm using html select's and when a new color is created I need to update the menu's for the vector shapes (info held in li's) that have been created. I am iterating through those in the color variables constructor using this:

```
var colorVar = function(name, hexstring){
   this.name = name;
   this.color = hexstring;
   //append colors to drop downs
   $( "li" ).each(function( index ) {
   $(this).context.childNodes[4].append("<option value='blue'>" + this.name + "</option>");
  });
}
```

but when i run that ^^ code i get this error:
     Uncaught TypeError: $(...).context.childNodes[4].append is not a function

when i run a console.log($(this).context.childNodes[4]) from within the each() i get

```
<select class='colorList'>
    <option value='blue'>primary color</option>
</select>
```

for every shape that i have made, so its definitely iterating through them.
(fyi i added primary color non-dynamically just as a test)

how do i append to the inside of the select?

Any other suggestions welcome!

(also Jquery is definitely working so its not an issue with including it in the html ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`.append()` is not a native javascript function. You can use `.insertAdjacentHTML()` to achieve what you want.

```
.....  .childNodes[4]
           .insertAdjacentHTML( 'beforeend', "<option value='blue'>" +
                                                  this.name + "</option>" );
```

Comment: thanks a lot! also would like to add for others who view this that the this.name within the insertAdjacentHTML() didnt work because 'this' became $(this), so i just used the original input variable name!!

Answer (score 0):

Why not just select the drop down using it's class and do it like this:

```
$(".colorList").append("<option value='blue'>"+this.name+"</option>");
```